# Некорректное отображение хинта ссылки на вопрос из комментария

Tags: дефект, дизайн, комментарии, ссылки

При отображении хинта на ссылку из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572819/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C#comment753563_572819) наблюдается проблема как с содержимым, так и с обрамлением:

[image: проблемный хинт]

Comment: Проблема с `title` имеется, а вот отображение полное, без странных обрезаний. Фотошоп? :) Chrome 53.

Comment: @Other не фотошоп, а firefox :) В других браузерах не проверял.

Comment: А где тогда Вы нарисовали прикольную красную обводку? :)

Comment: @Other для такого достаточно mspaint. Но речь-то не о самой обводке, а об отсутствии рамки справа.

Comment: Да, в FF проблема есть. Вероятно проблема браузера, а не сайта.

Comment: @Other без браузеров у сайта бы вовсе проблем не было :)

Comment: Как и самого сайта :)